# Rendering transparency

Tags: rendering, transparency

Is it possible to make parts of an image/animation render transparent?
[image]

I rendered this cube in the regular render image way. But is there a way to make the area around the cube transparent when rendering or before rendering?

Comment: Do you want it to cast shadow as well? Or only transparent bg?

Comment: thx, I just want the area around the cube to be transparent. So I see the cube in the render, but all the area around it transparent - no shadow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Go to Properties editor, Render Settings, Film panel, and enable Render Transparent.

[See this blender docs page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/film.html)

Answer (score 3):

To add to TheLabCat's answer, you can also use the *Holdout* node to make an object transparent. In Cycles you'll have to enable the *Render > Film > Transparent* option to make it work.

[image]